# Particular microSD card is not working with camera

Tags: memory-card

I was using an 8GB microSD card with a Canon PowerShot SX150 IS camera. It was functioning correctly. One day when I took a picture, it prompted me: `Memory Card Error`. But I was able to display old photos. However it was taking an unexpectedly long time to display any photo, and was hanging after displaying 3-4 photos.

Today I made a backup of photos from my Windows 7 PC, and deleted them from the memory card. I also formatted the memory card fully. And my OS was displaying it empty. Now when I used the same card with my camera, it gives me the same error and shows me deleted photos.

If I read the memory card in my PC through the camera, it doesn't show me all photos. I am able to delete visible photos but I can't delete their folder. And next time when I again read the memory card, all the photos are there.

I believe my OS is failing in formatting the memory card or deleting photos from memory card.

What should I do?

**Notes:**

- Other microSD cards are working fine in my camera.
- Since it is a microSD card, there is no notch on the card to make it read-only.

Answer (score 1):

Try formatting it with/**in the camera**.

If that fails, be glad you didn't lose the old photos from it, and **get it replaced** if it's got a guarantee and doen't cost more to fulfill the guarantee than a new card would, or **chuck it** if it fails either condition.

I've had a brand new memory card fail on its first use, with 70+ pictures on it - I eventually got 20 or so of those off the thing. You were lucky to lose so little.

Comment: I have tried to format it through camera. But it fails. Any operation from camera takes too much time and result in fail. And I feel card is not damaged otherwise it should create problem with mobile and PC too.